# Advertising network for publishers, do any have an API?

Tags: api, publishing, ads, adsense

I've got a site called http://www.manglebracket.com. It's a handy little web app for converting Word documents to HTML.

I want to monetize it with Adsense-style ads, but the standard "paste this JavaScript into your site" won't work for my use case. Basically, the user uploads a Word doc and goes to a "workspace" page where they choose options and tweak the HTML just how they like it. I'd love to show an ad on that page which is relevant to the the document they just uploaded, but the page is short-lived and session-protected, so relying on search engine indexing won't fly at all.

If there were an advertising API that allowed me to send over ***"relevance content"*** and get back an ad, which I then slapped on the site, that would be great. But I have no idea if such a thing exists. Doesn't seem to for Google Adsense. The Yahoo Publisher Network says they offer "Advanced ad targeting and display capabilities can improve the relevance of your results" but I can't find any more info about that.

Anyone know about a publisher advertising platform with a server-side (hopefully REST) API I could just grab an ad from, and get paid when the user clicks it?

I guess the larger issue here is, *how do people show relevant advertising on web applications where everything is dynamic and private*?

**Edit**

I haven't found what I'm looking for yet, but after Googling around I have a better idea of what I'm looking for. Essentially I need a

*dynamic real-time contextual ad web service for publishers*.

Proximic.com looks promising. Perhaps the real-time part is what makes this difficult. All the services I've found rely on spidering, which is done relatively infrequently. Real-time dynamic would be a lot more server-intensive.

**Update 1/14/2010**

I've given up, I believe no such thing exists. That's OK, I can just use generic display advertising, but it's a shame because *context* exists right there in a server-side variable, if only some ad service would receive it.

Comment: So darkporter thinks no such thing exists, but I'm willing to bet things have changed since, or that some ad network exists somewhere (possibly not publicly available), that would allow ads to be served according to context provided by the publisher.

Comment: Perhaps it was a mistake to "invest", hmmm.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out you can use AdSense in an iframe, which is a reasonable solution. Also the upcoming [AdSense for Ajax](http://code.google.com/apis/afa/) is pretty much exactly what I'm looking for, but it appears to be in private beta still.

Answer (score 0):

ContextWeb and Kontera are 2 that deliver real-time relevant ads for dynamic content.

Comment: I just emailed both of them, didn't see any mention of an API on their sites, but we'll see what they say. Thanks for the ideas.

Answer (score 0):

The best I can suggest for right now is a **creative alternative solution**, a crude workaround, that would at least increase the relevance of ads a little bit, and hence increase adsense revenue.

You know where you advertise your service - financial, engineering, fiction writers, whatever.

Create distinct htmlized-doc view pages for each of the main categories, with a sample doc in place.  Make sure these pages get spidered.  When you convert a word doc, from the words in it, work out which page to redirect to for the view of their doc.

It's coarse grained, but better than not doing anything at all.

Answer (score 0):

It shouldn't be too much trouble to display relevant AdSense ads with the content. The main thing is to allow the Google crawler to access the pages that the user sees. You would have to make sure that the URL of the converted document includes enough information in it to uniquely identify and serve said page. If the page is password-protected, add a login to your system that allows access to all those pages and go to your AdSense console to add the login to Google's system so that it can get in.

If you can, include a topic keyword in the generated URL, either based on the title or perhaps looking for the most used keyword phrase.

Of course, you'll need to keep an eye out for inappropriate/illegal content. Some kind of basic scanning to filter out things that don't fit with AdSense policies.

Comment: That won't work because "the page is short-lived and session-protected, so relying on search engine indexing won't fly at all".  The questioner wants appropriate ads served on a page when the user first sees their converted doc.  The user will be long gone by the time the spider gets there.

Comment: But AdSense can do some good guessing using just keywords in the URL and the crawler actually comes by pretty quickly these days anyhow. Some clever URL generation for the converted documents and some other things could make it work.

Comment: That said, I can't but think that the CTR on ads displayed on documents that you're converting will just be terrible. I'm not sure the ad model works here in general.

Answer (score 0):

I believe http://www.retailigence.com has an API that you can use for real-time lookup of location and contextual ads.